# Why is ICustomTypeDescriptor not found

Tags: sqlite, f#, portable-class-library

I made a PCL for Windows, Android, and iOS with the library in FSharp. I finally got the SqlDataProvider working, but whenever I write code to try to access a property of an entity in a query, the module declaration shows an error saying that ICustomTypeDescriptor was not found on System.ComponentModel. Also, I did not get any intellisense on the properties for the transaction entity.

```
module CashFlowData

open FSharp.Data.Sql
open System.IO
open System
open CashFlow

let [<Literal>] resolutionPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "\packages\System.Data.SQLite.dll";
let [<Literal>] connectionString = "DataSource=" + __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"\CashFlowDb.sqlite3;Version=3"

type private sql = SqlDataProvider<
                    ConnectionString = connectionString,
                    DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.SQLITE,
                    SQLiteLibrary = Common.SQLiteLibrary.SystemDataSQLite,
                    ResolutionPath = resolutionPath,
                    UseOptionTypes = true>

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

let transactions (period : Period) (budget : Budget) =
query { 
    for transaction in ctx.Main.Transaction do
    where (transaction.Date <= period.End && transaction.Date >= period.End
            && transaction.Fk_BudgetId = budget.Id)
    select transaction
}
```